# Codename One - Avoid screen size change on Android on app startup

Tags: codenameone

This issue produce two unwanted effects on Android:

- one execution of the `SizeChangedListener` (at app startup) that I
  don't want;
- a visible and unwanted resizing of the Form background
  (with the option `Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED_FILL`) after the app is
  just started.

The following code, tested on Samsung Galaxy S8+, produces this log:

> 12-18 00:49:45.594 D/SizeChangedListener(17264): **[EDT] 0:0:0,22 - Initial Screen size: 1080 * 2008**
>   12-18 00:49:45.596 I/System.out(17264): showKeyboard false
>   12-18 00:49:45.623 D/Codename One(17264): **sizechanged: 1080 1945** com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneView@10f7aa8
>   12-18 00:49:45.627 D/libEGL  (17264): loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
>   12-18 00:49:45.633 I/WebViewFactory(17264): Loading com.google.android.webview version 60.0.3112.107 (code 311210750)
>   12-18 00:49:45.634 D/SizeChangedListener(17264): **[EDT] 0:0:0,61 - SizeChangedListener on "hi Form" invoked...**
>   12-18 00:49:45.635 D/SizeChangedListener(17264): **[EDT] 0:0:0,64 - New Screen size: 1080 * 1945**

This is the very simple code that I used to replicate this issue:

```
public void start() {
    if (current != null) {
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.add(new Label("Hi world"));
    Log.p("Initial Screen size: " + hi.getWidth() + " * " + hi.getHeight());
    hi.show();

    hi.addSizeChangedListener(l -> {
        Log.p("SizeChangedListener on \"hi Form\" invoked...");
        Log.p("New Screen size: " + hi.getWidth() + " * " + hi.getHeight());
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just relay the size of the view and the events we get from Android. The reason for this is probably related to the status bar which might be hidden on launch and is then added for compatibility.

We have an RFE to [enable status bar hiding on Android](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2220) which might resolve this issue although with Android it might create a similar issue in other devices where the status bar isn't hidden by default...

Comment: In the while, as a temporary workaround, I simply added `TestUtils.waitFor(500);` just before the `hi.show();`. It (apparently?) solved the problem of the unwanted resizing of the Form background. Can you suggest me a better workaround? Thank you :)

Comment: That's not something you should do as it can cause a crash. I would just set a different background  pattern if it's a problem.

Comment: Why can it cause a crash?

Comment: You are sleeping on the EDT during a lifecycle callback which can cause the OS to think that the app isn't responsive and kill it.